# Is there a way to enter text into address bar indirectly?

Tags: javascript, php

For instance I would have a text field and the user could write something and if they pressed a button or something it would enter the text into the address bar? Using javascript or php.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like

```
location.href = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
```

Comment: Something like this should be avoided.

Comment: Why so? Its a safe way to do a redirect without triggering any anti-popup bells.

Comment: Thanks! I looked and couldn't find an answer I suppose this must have been an easy noob question. I'll except when it lets me.